# Why does my transparent png have artifacts around it?

Tags: transparency

I'm trying to project an image onto an object using UV mapping and an Image Texture node. The png I am using is transparent, but when it's projected onto the object there are places where it is not. It seems to have artifacts. Both my image and UV are both set to 4096 x 4096. Can you please assist? I would be very appreciative if you could help. Thank you.

[image: Artifacts in transparent image]

Comment: Changing the alpha type (in the Node Editor - in the Properties panel)  from "Straight" to "Premultiplied" worked. But I do not why this worked or if there is a better way.

Comment: are you not supposed to use the Alpha out of the Image Texture and plug it into a Mix Layer with a Transparency node plugged into its second input? And where do you find this Straight/Premultiplied option?

Comment: @moonboots I tried that and it didn't work. But if you look at the bottom of the image, where it says "Straight". That is where I changed it to premultiplied. In order to see this menu you have to have the image node selected and bring up the properties menu by pressing N.